# Java illegal start of type?

Tags: java

I have this:

```
class undefinedException extends Exception {
     super("Its not defined!");
}
```

But I am getting:
illegal start of type

Whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It should be

```
class UndefinedException extends Exception {

       public UndefinedException() {
          super("Its not defined!");
       }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `super` call inside a constructor.